# Why i'm getting "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:A problem occurred when attempting to contact the server"

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, database-connection, datasource

My application was working fine from the morning, in the evening suddenly I got the below exception.

> SQLException while attempting to connect: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]A problem occurred when attempting to contact the server (Server returned: Connection reset). Please ensure that the server parameters passed to the driver are correct and that the server is running. Also ensure that the maximum number of connections have not been exceeded for this server.

Can anyone please let me know what is the solution for this.

Thanks
Rudresh

Comment: At a guess, your database server's inaccessible for some reason

Comment: I suggest taking the last two sentences of the error message literally.

Comment: Got to the CF Administrator. Then go to datasources. Run verify on the desired datasource. See if it can even connect to the DB.

Comment: I'd also check the SQL server itself to make sure the user that ColdFusion uses to connect hasn't been disabled. It's easy to lock the account if you hit it with too many bad connections (or at least your accounts _should_ be limited to lock out any users with excess failed logins).

Comment: Thanks, guys for your valuable comments. The issue has been fixed, the problem was we are using one NDQ DB for integration server, in that DB server our credential got expired because of that I was getting that exception after updating my password the issue has been fixed.